# What are mandrakes? Are they edible? How are they prepared?

Tags: food-safety, history

Mandrakes (*mandragora*) are mentioned in the Bible as an aid to fertility (cf. [Genesis 30:14](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=1&ch=30&l=14-#x)), but what exactly are mandrakes? I hear they are poisonous, have narcotic properties, or aid with fertility.

Are they edible raw, cooked only (like rhubarb), or neither? If they are edible, does one eat their roots, leaves, or both?

Comment: Did you try to google it?? See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandragora_officinarum. They are hallucinogenic and narcotic. In sufficient quantities, it induces a state of unconsciousness and delirium. Relevance to fertility is pure folklore.

Comment: In other words, don't eat them.

Comment: You can buy mandrake extract, but as most would agree this is not a safe substance to cook with. The mandrake extract is used in the Basque liqueur [Mandrágora](https://www.absinthes.com/en/liqueur-mandragora-liqueur-100-cl-p2029) for example.